# Custom workflow action - added new FieldBind and Parameter to .actions4, but not showing up in .xaml designer?

Tags: visual-studio, workflow-activity

I'm updating a custom workflow action to add a new text parameter.  I've updated the `.actions4` XML with a new `FieldBind` element mapped to a new `Parameter` element.  I've cleaned and rebuilt the project in VS.  But the new parameter is not showing up as available in the `.xaml` workflow designer file.

What do I need to do to make the new parameter available in the workflow designer file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, kind of an embarrassing facepalm situation, but I forgot to add the new parameter as an Argument for the workflow action.

[image: screenshot of arguments button]

Don't know why I thought it would add it automatically... ¯\*(ツ)*/¯